# How to connect your Android App with metamask?

Tags: android, kotlin, blockchain, metamask, wallet-connect

So I am using wallet `connectV2`, what I am trying to do is to connect my `metamask` wallet with my App and I am trying to follow the walletConnect2 sample app code. But I am having trouble connecting it as there is no popup appearing when selecting `metamask` unlike their own wallet sample app. So, please can anybody tell me what should I do or need to change(parameter/relayServerUrl) in order to connect with metamask. I have provided a pic also.
[image]

Comment: I have also faced the same issue and I have tried walletconnect first version https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib But that also was having some issue wen proguard enabled. finally the implementation from https://github.com/Haoxiqiang/android-wallet-connect-sdk helped me.

Comment: Still not working for me can you refer me any tutorial. I want to work with only wallet connectV2 as we know that V2 is not backwards compatible with Wallet Connect v1

Comment: But v1 is compatible with v2 i guess. You can check my sample from here:
https://github.com/jemshit/WalletConnect

Comment: Please include your code as text, using `\`\`\`java` at the start and `\`\`\`` at the end.

Comment: I'm also having trouble connecting to metamask using the example code that exists on the official repository: https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2/tree/develop/sign/dapp. I replaced the `projectId` with one I generated for myself but when I press the `DEEPLINK` button, metamask opens but it does not prompt to approve the connection.

Comment: Has anyone had any success with this issue? I am still facing this exact issue. I tried the following: https://medium.com/coinmonks/connecting-your-mobile-apps-with-your-web3-identity-55b7be30e407 and https://medium.com/@hira.siddiqui/connecting-your-mobile-apps-with-your-web3-identity-ef0416033419 but still not getting the pop up on Metamask, Rainbow or Trust Wallet. OpenSea's login works perfectly fine for all of these three.

Answer (score 1):

The library seems to be maintained: [`WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2`](https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2) and there's a [documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/kotlin/sign/wallet-usage). There's also a specific tutorial: [Beginner’s Guide to the WalletConnect v2.0 Sign SDK for Android Developers](https://medium.com/walletconnect/beginner-guide-to-walletconnect-v2-0-sign-protocol-for-android-developers-936293e30700). Call `CoreClient.initialize()` first, alike the tutorial suggests. Also, the address need to be in [CAIP-10](https://github.com/ChainAgnostic/CAIPs/blob/master/CAIPs/caip-10.md) format. While screenshots of code are of no use, unless there is a stack-trace provided, there is no problem. "It does not work" is no sufficient  error description.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late answering this but Metamask does not yet support WalletConnect V2 . You can test wallet from this link and you will find same behaviour:
https://lab.web3modal.com/

It will be supported after June 15 according to the announcement below:
https://medium.com/walletconnect/weve-reset-the-clock-on-the-walletconnect-v1-0-shutdown-now-scheduled-for-june-28-2023-ead2d953b595